# get the attributes of object recieved from mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, object

I have a alerts collection in my mongodb..
I wish to get the attributes of the object present in my alerts model, i have written the following code....

```
Alert.find({},function(err,alerts){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log(alerts);
    alerts.forEach(function(result){
        console.log(result.name);
        console.log(result._id);
    });
});
```

In first console, i am getting all the objects of alerts model,
but in second console it is 'Undefined' even result.name is present in the model..

But the _id is generated by mongodb itself and im able to get that id..

```
From 1st console:
  { __v: 0,
    _id: 55128d3a1b35c366eb974285,
    brand: 'SanDisk',
    name: 'SanDisk Cruzer Blade 8 GB Pen Drives Black (Combo of 2)',
    source:
     { name: 'Snapdeal',
       productId: '141951',
       inStock: true} 
 }
From 2nd console:
   Undefined

From 3rd console
   55128d3a1b35c366eb974285
```

Cannot able to get the problem, what is the correct way of doing this..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mongoose.. 
and the solution for the above is applying lean() function

i.e

```
Alert.find({}).lean().exec(function(err,alerts){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log(alerts);
    alerts.forEach(function(result){
        console.log(result.name);
        console.log(result._id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your original question never mentioned you were using the mongoose Node.js driver.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here but you have to understand that MongoDB [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method returns a [**`cursor`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the documents that match the query criteria. So what you see in the `console.log(alerts)` is actually the cursor returned. When the `find()` method “returns documents,” the method is actually returning a cursor to the documents. So what you see in the first and third console outputs are cursor objects and properties.

You need to add a [**`toArray()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) method to the resulting cursor from the `Alert.find()` operation, e.g.

```
Alert.find({}).toArray(function(err, alerts){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log(alerts);
    alerts.forEach(function (result) {
        console.log(result.name);
        console.log(result._id);
    });
});
```

The **`toArray()`** method returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all the documents into RAM and exhausting the cursor.